# certificate transparency logs-API limited range for entries

Tags: python, cloudflare, lets-encrypt, google-apis-explorer, certificate-transparency

just wondering if the http://ct.googleapis.com/logs/argon2021/ct/v1/get-entries?start=12345&end=12345 has a limit in the range.

right now I can just get up to 20 entries in that API. for example I want to get recent records and the current tree size is 1000. I have to do something like this

http://ct.googleapis.com/logs/argon2021/ct/v1/get-entries?start=1&end=20
http://ct.googleapis.com/logs/argon2021/ct/v1/get-entries?start=21&end=40 
http://ct.googleapis.com/logs/argon2021/ct/v1/get-entries?start=41&end=60
.
.
.
until I can get 1000 records instead of just like

http://ct.googleapis.com/logs/argon2021/ct/v1/get-entries?start=1&end=1000

is there a limit per operator? what I observed now are the following data
20 for Google
1000 for Cloudflare
200 for Let's Encrypt

if yes, what is the limit per call? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried google CT log API, it seems that google only supports at most 31 like:
http://ct.googleapis.com/logs/argon2021/ct/v1/get-entries?start=1&end=31
When I try to add more records like
http://ct.googleapis.com/logs/argon2021/ct/v1/get-entries?start=1&end=32
I got same response.
FYI

Comment: thanks for your answer. I forgot to update my question here. but yes, I got the answer from google groups. thank you anyway. :)